# What's the function of "alternate full address:s:value" property in a RDP file?

Tags: remote-desktop

Regarding the `alternate full address:s:value` property, I can see what's stated on the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/rdp-files#connection-information):

> Specifies an alternate name or IP address of the remote computer.

But in practical terms, what does it do?

Comment: I'm guessing it will use an alternative remote server if the first one is down or responds that it is overloaded or similar. My work remote does this an I sometimes get logged in to a different server than normal (transparently other than displaying that I connected to a different sever name - for example instead of server4 it will say "server4 (server3)" an connect to server 3.

Comment: Oh okay, that would make sense.

Comment: Someone else asked the same question a few years back which contradicts @DavidPostill's guess: https://serverfault.com/questions/955042/difference-between-rdp-file-settings-alternate-full-address-and-full-address